# Conky not showing desktop icons

Tags: compiz, xfce, conky, desktop-icons

I have installed the Inifinity style to Conky on my Ubuntu 12.04 system using XFCE4 as my WM and Desktop.

http://www.unixmen.com/infinity-a-stunning-theme-for-conky-ubuntu-linuxmint-fedora/

It works fine, problem is that my desktop icons won't display.

My `.conkyrc` file is here:

```
#########################################################################################
#    Conky Theme : Infinity                                                                                                                                                                                          #
#    Created by     : Harshit Yadav                                                                                                                                                                              #
#    Version           : 1.0                                                                                                                                                                                                  # 
#    Feel Free to distribute                                                                                                                                                                                         #
#    For Installation Instrcutions See Read Me                                                                                                                                                       #
########################################################################################


# Conky settings #
background yes
update_interval 1

cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2

override_utf8_locale yes

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

text_buffer_size 2048
#imlib_cache_size 0

temperature_unit fahrenheit

# Window specifications #

own_window yes
own_window_type override
own_window_class Conky
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below

border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0

## This Resolution is set according to the sreen resolution of 1366x768 
## Adjust Accoring to yours

minimum_size 1024 768
maximum_width 1024

alignment tr
gap_x 10
gap_y 55

# Graphics settings #
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

# Text settings #
use_xft yes
xftfont caviar dreams:size=8
xftalpha 0.5

uppercase no

temperature_unit celsius


default_color FFFFFF

# Lua Load  #
lua_load ~/.lua/scripts/haunted.lua
lua_draw_hook_pre clock_rings

## Adjust these fields according to the your screen size i have modded them for 1366X768

TEXT
${offset 600}${color EAEAEA}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=80}${time %l:%M %p}
${offset 650}${font}${voffset -84}${voffset 10}${color FFA300}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=42}${time %d} ${voffset -15}${color EAEAEA}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=22}${time  %B} ${time %Y}${font}${voffset 70}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=58}${offset -550}${time %A}${font}
${offset 650}${voffset -100}${font Ubuntu:pixelsize=10}${color FFA300}HD ${offset 9}$color${fs_free /} / ${fs_size /}${offset 30}${color FFA300}RAM ${offset 9}$color$mem / $memmax${offset 30}${color FFA300}CPU ${offset 9}$color${cpu cpu0}%
${voffset 10}${offset 270}${color 2c2c2c}${hr 4}
${image ~/.conky/rev-eng.png}


${offset 130}${voffset 222}${font Santana:size=9:style=Bold}root : ${font Santana:size=9}${fs_used /}/${fs_size /}
${offset 130}${voffset 10}${font Santana:size=9:style=Bold}home: ${font Santana:size=9}${fs_used /home}/${fs_size /home}$font
${offset 120}${voffset 12}${color ffffff}${font Santana:size=9:style=Bold}swap: ${font Santana:size=8} ${swap} / ${swapfree}$font
${offset 570}${voffset -110} ${color EAEAEA}Linux ${kernel} kernel
${offset 570}${voffset 5} Uptime :${uptime}
${offset 825}${voffset -80}${color ffffff}${font Santana:size=10:style=Bold}${exec whoami}@${nodename}
${offset 825}${voffset 0}${color ffffff}${font Santana:size=8}${top name 5} ${top mem 5}
${offset 700}${voffset 130}${color ffffff}${font Santana:size=8}IP Address :${addr eth0}
${offset 705}${voffset 10}${color ffffff}${font Santana:size=8}Down :${downspeed eth0} k/s ${offset 8}Up:${upspeed eth0} k/s
${offset 703}${voffset 10}${color ffffff}${font Santana:size=8}TCP Connections: ${tcp_portmon 1 65535 count}
```

A lot of places on the NET have suggested changing settings on the `own_window_type override` part, I have tried all 3 of them; `normal, desktop and override`

`desktop` and `normal` only display a black background and totally mask my desktop. While as `override` will at least display my wallpaper.

If I right click on it anywhere it pops up my right click menu for the desktop. So it's getting there but no icons.

```
http://i.imgur.com/stthsQP.png
http://i.imgur.com/Zr9WBmp.png
```

Also if I right click on where an icon should be it display the popup menu for that file, so it works just doesn't display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this problem is caused by XFWM and Compositor. This can be fixed by enabling compositor for XFWM:

```
Settings -> Settings Manager -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Compositor -> Enable Display Compositing
```

Default settings enabled and just enable it. Then change your config for conky to this:

```
own_window yes
own_window_type desktop
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
```

It's now working 100% for me in XFCE.